# Unexpandable Window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resizable

While using JFrame, is it possible to have the window unable to be expanded by the user?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear at all. From the answers (and your reaction) I can now guess what you want, but not from the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable%28boolean%29) is what you want. It explains it setResizable() method.

EDIT: If you would like a quick introduction, say your JFrame object is called `myFrame`, then, to make it non-resizable,

```
myFrame.setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need call [`setResizable(false)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable%28boolean%29) on your `JFrame`, e.g.:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(500, 300);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: No problem :) Since the answers appear to have helped you, I've edited your question a little. I changed "screen" to "window" for clarity, since a JFrame is a window and not a screen.